# Using column versions for time series

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

In the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design-time-series#dont_exploit_atomicity_of_single_rows) there is a text for which I can't totally understand the reason:

> **When working with time series, do not leverage the transactional behavior of rows.** Changes to data in an existing row should be stored as a new, separate row, not changed in the existing row. This is an easier model to construct, and it enables you to maintain a history of activity without relying upon column versions.

The last sentence is not obvious and concrete, so it doesn't convince me. For now, using versioning for updating the cell's data still looks to me like a good fit for the update task. At least versions are managed by BigTable, so it's simplier solution.

Can anybody please provide more obvious explanation of why the versioning shouldn't be used in that use case?

Answer (score 1):

Earlier in that page under [Patterns for row key design](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design-time-series#patterns_for_row_key_design), a bit more detail is explained. The high level view being that using row keys instead of column versions will:

- Make it easier to run queries across your data, allowing for scanning of less data.
- Avoid going over the recommended maximum row size.

The one caveat being:

> **It is acceptable to use versions of a column where the use case is
>   actually amending a value, and the value's history is important**. For
>   example, suppose you did a set of calculations based on the closing
>   price of ZXZZT, and initially the data was mistakenly entered as
>   559.40 for the closing price instead of 558.40. In this case, it might be important to know the value's history in case the incorrect value
>   had caused other miscalculations.